# what does this array statement in verilog means and its vhdl counterpart

Tags: vhdl, verilog

im trying to code verilog and vhdl recently, there is something that im confused of

here is the sample code:

```
output [7:0] O ;

input [7:0] D ;

input A3 , A2 , A1 , A0 ;

reg [7:0] X [15:0];
```

what does the following statement means:

1)

```
X [{A3 , A2 , A1 , A0 }] = D;
```

2)

```
assign O = X [{A3 , A2 , A1 , A0 }];
```

and were i to make this statement in vhdl, how to make it?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets denote concatenation in verilog. So the input bits are combined into a word/vector, which serves an an index for array X. The 4 inputs bits can indeed address all 16 words in array x. It might be more clear to have input [3:0] A, which would allow to write X[A] = D and assign O = X[A]

Comment: Perhaps you could explain which element of D is assigned o an element of X?

Comment: D is a vector of 8 bits, a byte.
X is a memory of bytes with addresses of 4bits, so 16 addresses. Total 16 bytes.
iThe address is applied by Input port A3,A2,A1,A0.

If A3,A2,A1,A0 = 1,0,0,0, then the byte on D is registered on the 8th field in memory X.